# Save recording by AVAudioRecorder to Core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I'm trying to build a simple recording app that takes input from mic and saves the recording when you press stop, and the player retrieves the recording from local storage and plays it.

The following code allows user to record audio and saves it to a URL and plays it from the same URL.

What  I want to do is save audio to Coredata when I press stop, and retrieve audio from Coredata when I press play.

```
@IBOutlet weak var RecordBTN: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var AddBTN: UIButton!

// Variables handeling Recording and Playing
var SoundRecorder : AVAudioRecorder!
var SoundPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Keeps constraints when we run the app
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    setupRecorder() 
}

func setupRecorder()
{
    // Format: Lossless audio
    // Quality: Max of raw value
    // Bit Rate: 320 Kb/s [ AppleMusic: 256 Kb/s, Spotify: 320 Kb/s]
    let recordSettings : [String : AnyObject] =
        [AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(value: kAudioFormatAppleLossless as UInt32),
         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue as NSNumber,
         AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000 as NSNumber,
         AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2 as NSNumber,
         AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0 as NSNumber]

    do {

        // Initiallizing SoundRecorder
        // as [NSObject : AnyObject] after recordSettings
        try SoundRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: getFileURL(),
                                            settings: recordSettings as [String : AnyObject])

    } catch {
        // Catches any error
        print("Something's went wrong with setting up the audio")
    }

    // Preparing sound recorder to record
    SoundRecorder.delegate = self
    SoundRecorder.prepareToRecord()


}


func getCacheDir() -> String
{
    // Where audio files will be held
    // Search inside documents inside of the app
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory,
                                                    FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true) as [String]
    return paths[0]
}

func getFileURL() -> URL
{
    // Finding the file path to the specified file name
    let path = (getCacheDir() as NSString).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    return filePath
}


func preparePlayer()
{
    do{
        try SoundPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: getFileURL())
    } catch {
        print("Somethingwrong with the Sound Player")
    }
    SoundPlayer.delegate = self
    SoundPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    SoundPlayer.volume = 10.0
}



@IBAction func Record(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (sender.titleLabel?.text == "Record")
    {
        SoundRecorder.record();
        sender.setTitle("Stop", for: UIControlState())
        sender.setImage(UIImage (named: "StopBTN"), for: UIControlState())
        PlayBTN.isEnabled = false
        progressBar.progress = Float(SoundRecorder.currentTime)

    }
    else
    {
        SoundRecorder.stop();
        sender.setTitle("Record", for: UIControlState())
        sender.setImage(UIImage (named: "RecordBTN"), for: UIControlState())
        PlayBTN.isEnabled = true
    }

}


    @IBAction func Play(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if(sender.titleLabel?.text == "Play")
    {
        RecordBTN.isEnabled = false
        sender.setTitle("Stop", for: UIControlState())
        sender.setImage(UIImage (named: "StopBTN"), for: UIControlState())
        preparePlayer()
        SoundPlayer.play()
    }
    else if (sender.titleLabel?.text == "Stop" || (SoundPlayer.currentTime == SoundPlayer.duration))
    {
        SoundPlayer.stop()
        sender.setTitle("Play", for: UIControlState())
        sender.setImage(UIImage (named: "PlayBTN"), for: UIControlState())
        RecordBTN.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

I added a `Recordings` Entity in Coredata, still confused on what to use as attributes, don't know If I will save the URL or binaryfiles.

Comment: Store the URL to the file in CoreData. Not the actual file. That's it. Here is a direct link to the recommendations and guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Performance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH25-SW11

Comment: As Sneak said, store the URL in Core Data, not the actual file. 

I will go a step further and recommend only storing a **relative** URL in CoreData. Your app's location on the filesystem will change during app upgrades. The URL you store in Core Data should be relative to your app's documents directory. You can then determine the location of the Documents directory at runtime.